# Error while getting SelectedDate from ASP:Calendar, Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I have an `<asp:Calendar>` in my code and I want to do is that when a date is clicked, it will show  the selected date on the page.

```
 protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "The selected date is " + Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
}
```

I followed the code instructions from [here, Microsoft's website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

But I get this error.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Are `Calendar1` or `Label1` added dynamically to the page?

Comment: Calendar1 is <asp:Calendar>'s ID and Label1 is already on the page that is set to 'No Date Selected'

Comment: Can you post your actual markup?

Comment: MasterPage.master >>  http://pastebin.com/5E4JKwvx

Comment: MasterPage.master.cs >>  http://pastebin.com/wAWBYxVH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you have your Label1 inside the ContentPlaceHolder. When your .aspx child page uses that placeholder, the label is removed from masterpage. So in the SelectionChanged event it doesn't find your Label1.

Move your Label outside of the mainContent ContentPlaceHolder

Answer (score 0):

I copied the same code as you pasted and its working for me. I am getting the date properly on Selection_Changed event.
    protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string tst = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        }

the error you have mentioned can occur if your asp:Calendar control is in UpdatePanel.

Comment: I have faced similar errors when I use Ajax update panel and the controls are inside the update panel